# UDF/Procedure with control flow that returns a table

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am kinda stuck with the limitations of UDFs/stored Procedures in Snowflake and wonder what I am missing. I feel like there has to be a solution, but I can't see it right now, so maybe som new input from stackoverflow can help me.

I want something (UDF/Procedure) that has an input and returns a table. I created a stored procedure that generates the SQl-Statement. But in the stored procedure I can only return a single value and no table.
My stored procedure is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DWH.TEMP.getAccounts(NODE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
     var maxLevel = 0;
      function executeSQL(SQL ) {
      
          // Prepare statement.
          var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
                 {
                 sqlText: SQL
                 }
              );
          // Execute Statement
          var res = stmt.execute();
          res.next();
          return res.getColumnValue(1);
     }                                                         
                                                          
     maxLevel= executeSQL(" SELECT MAX(LEVEL) as Max_Level FROM DWH.MART.VDIM_ACCOUNT"); 
     var sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM DWH.MART.VDIM_ACCOUNT WHERE ";
     var sqlWhere = "";
     for (var i = 0;i<=maxLevel;i++)
     {
       sqlWhere += "Group_L"+ i +" in (\'"+NODE_NAME+"\')";
       if(i<maxLevel)
       {
       sqlWhere += " OR ";
       }
     }
     sqlString += sqlWhere;
    return sqlString;
'
```

If I execute this with a node, for example with call GETACCOUNTS('Test') I get the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountID 
FROM   dwh.mart.vdim_account
WHERE  group_l0 IN ( 'TEST' )
        OR group_l1 IN ( 'TEST' )
        OR group_l2 IN ( 'TEST' )
        OR group_l3 IN ( 'TEST' )
        OR group_l4 IN ( 'TEST' )
        OR group_l5 IN ( 'TEST' )
```

But I want the result of above SQL-Statement returnes as a table or list. How do I do this in Snowflake?

I am stuck because I need the for loop to dynamically generate my SQL-Statement. I can only use loops in JS UDFs, but I can only execute SQL in SQL UDFs.

Comment: Currently, Snowflake stored procedures cannot return tables. The only option to return tables is using a user defined table function, UDTF. However, JavaScript UDTFs do not have access to the "snowflake" object that can run queries. If the returned table is small (a few megabytes) you can return a variant with a JSON array. It's pretty easy to flatten that into rows and columns. Another option is to have the SP write a table using the "snowflake" JavaScript api object.

Comment: How would you write a table using the javascript API?
Can you elaborate on this?

Do you mean creating a temp table in the stored procedure and filling it?

Comment: Do you want to execute the SQL that your SP is generating and then store the results in a table or list? If so, what  are you then going to be doing with this data?

Comment: @Schnurres instead of returning a table, you can have the SP create a table (or as many as you want) by executing SQL statements using the "snowflake" object. They can be temporary, transient (no time travel) or regular tables. If you do have the SP create a table, be careful of row-by-row inserts. That will be very slow due to Snowflake's design being optimized for bulk inserts. You can batch several thousand rows into a VALUES clause and run the insert that way.

Comment: @NickW Exactly. I want the dynamically generate the sql and then execute it and store the result in a table or list.

The result will be used as a filter in other tables.

Comment: @GregPavlik the number of rows won't be a problem because it can be 1,5k rows max.

Thanks! I will try that.